# Graphql Appolo Server does not resolve bound function as a field

Tags: typescript, express, graphql

I am using Apollo Server with TypeOrm.
I want to make nested relation "lazy", so I wrote a few function to fetch the creator of my post in async way.

```
const fetchUser = async (userId: string): Promise<User> => {
    return await User.findOne(userId) as User;
}
const transformPost = (post: Post): Post => {
    return { ...post, creator: fetchUser.bind(null, post.creatorId) } as Post;
}
```

Then in resolvers I return like that.

```
return {
            posts: posts.slice(0, realLimit).map(post => transformPost(post)),
            hasMore: posts.length === realLimitPlusOne
        }
```

So the post return object looks like that.

```
{
  id: 302,
  title: 'Love Affair, or the Case of the Missing Switchboard Operator (Ljubavni slucaj ili tragedija sluzbenice P.T.T.)',
  text: 'In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam faucibus cursus urna. Ut tellus.',
  points: 0,
  creatorId: 1,
  created_at: 2020-03-09T22:34:04.000Z,
  updated_at: 2021-03-10T10:16:39.088Z,
  creator: [Function: bound fetchUser]
}
```

But when I call it in my GraphQL, I am getting

```
 "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field User.username.",
```

Comment: why? resolvers are already a system of lazy 'fetchers'

Comment: no, it does not work just like that

Comment: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Post.creator

Comment: explain the difference

Comment: If I don't bind function to creatort I get : 
Cannot return null for non-nullable field Post.creator.
But seems I found how to fix it .

```
@ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.posts, { lazy: true })
    creator: User;
```